# Allow user to add option to autocomplete list (typeahead bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

There are many threads and samples out there about [typeahead](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) (https://gist.github.com/1866739) and also a forked version, but I simply cannot find anything on allowing the user to "add" what he/she has written, if it's not already in the list. If the user continues typing when there are 0 results, the results `ul` is hidden...

[image: typeahead]
[image]

I'd like to add an `<li>` that is the value of input (that I know how to do), but **the dropdown disappears if the user continues typing input and there are 0 matches**.

When I come down to 1 match "count li" for amount: "1" works, but to count 0 doesn't work, it's as if the entire list is "repopulated" again if there are no matches.

Links, hints, or examples would be much appreciated!

Comment: You mean like a `CTRL+L+A` for "Add current text in input to custom list"?

Comment: By Ctrl+L+A you mean a keyboard shortcut for what I'm trying to accomplish? If so, "Ctrl+L+A" would be a cool "next step", especially as it's in my pipleine to make the website keyboard friendly.

Comment: the normal behavior would be `choose or write your interest` and upon submit you would get the input box value the same way...

Comment: problem is that if I add an li that says "choose".. It doesn't show if the user keeps typing. =/

Comment: @balexandre that's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Alisso -- I'm not sure I fully understand, but why would you want to add an `<li>` ? For example, take a look at google.com normal search, choosing a value from the autocomplete is completely optional. The user can still submit the form with their own value...

Comment: This is an "add to list" function, and not a search, the few people who have tested the page don't come to the conclusion "write and press enter".

Comment: I guess I could add a button "add interest" next to the field and so if they choose from the list they'll "never get to the button" and if they keep writing and the list disappears they would click the button and it will probably be even easier for me to handle the input.

Comment: @Alisso -- that could work. I think "type and press enter" might work for people too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really don't get what is the issue, but I'm assuming that's because it is to easy and you just don't see it.

Instead of having a button to make the user to add it's own interest (instead of selecting it from the list - your `source`), you could simply accept the user value using `$('.typeahead').val();`

here is a [live demo](http://jsbin.com/ixefam/2), fell free to add your own items and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in order to effectively have them as the `typehead` source.

in your page, you could actually use `$.ajax()` to add the new item to your database at once, or wait until the user submit the form and add it.

Comment: This is what I've been looking for(!) Thank you!

Comment: @Alisso - That demo reminds me of the demos at the [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/new) site.